# Simple pointer problem in C - wrong value

Tags: c, pointers

I was working on something simple, using linked lists and I realized there is something I didn't understand. I can't figure out why the program below doesn't print 3 (it prints a random number). I think it's also weird that I get no errors at runtime and y is not NULL.

```
struct ceva
{
    int y;
};

typedef struct ceva str;

void do_something(str *x)
{
    str *p = (str *)malloc (sizeof (str));
    p->y = 3;
    x = p;
}

int main(void)
{
    str *y;
    do_something (y);
    printf ("%d", y->y);
}
```

Comment: +1 for presenting a complete, compilable program. I would have given +2 if you had included `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: thanks, i would have, but i didn't see the includes in the preview so i decided to remove them

Answer (score 4):

You're passing by value the `str x` to the function `do_something`.

Changing `x` in `do_something` will not change `y` in the `main` function. Either pass a reference to `y` in as follows:

```
void do_something(str **x)
{
    str *p = (str *)malloc (sizeof (str));
    p->y = 3;
    *x = p;
}

int main(void)
{
    str *y;
    do_something (&y);
    printf ("%d", y->y);
}
```

or make the function `do_something` return the address of the structure it allocated:

The following is the usual way of doing this in C.

```
str *do_something(void)
{
    str *p = (str *)malloc (sizeof (str));
    if (p)  // ensure valid pointer from malloc.
    {
        p->y = 3;
    }
    return p;
}

int main(void)
{
    str *y = do_something (y);
    printf ("%d", y->y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you want to do:

```
void do_something(str **x)
{
    str *p = (str *)malloc (sizeof (str));
    p->y = 3;
    *x = p;
}

int main(void)
{
    str *y;
    do_something (&y);
    printf ("%d", y->y);
}
```

Otherwise the copy of the passed pointer will be set to your desired value

Answer (score 1):

in order to change y, you need to send &y, so do_something parameter will actually need to be str **x

```
struct ceva{
int y; 
};
typedef struct ceva str;
void do_something(str **x)
{
str *p = (str *)malloc (sizeof (str));
p->y = 3;
*x = p;
}
int main(void)
{
str *y;
do_something (&y);
printf ("%d", y->y);
}
```

Comment: fixed some styling and a typo in do_something

Answer (score 1):

Since, `C` is *pass by value*, `y` is retaining back pointing to some garbage, which it's state was in `main()`. To actually do what you intended, `do_something(..)` should return a reference of type str*.

```
str* do_something(str *x)
{
    str *p = (str *)malloc (sizeof (str));
    p->y = 3;
    x = p;
    return x ;
}
```

// And the returned value needs to be collected.

```
str *y;  // It's a good practice to set y to NULL. Do this instead. str *y = NULL ;
y = do_something (y);
```

Answer (score 1):

`x = p;` assigns the location of the allocated memory to the ***local*** variable `x` which is promptly forgotten. Either return the address of the allocated struct, like:

```
str* do_something() {
    str *p = (str *)malloc (sizeof (str));
    p->y = 3;
    return p;
}
int main() {
    str * y = do_something();
    printf("%d", y->y);
}
```

Or supply an address `do_something` can write an address[sic] to:

```
void do_something(str** x) {
    str *p = (str *)malloc (sizeof (str));
    p->y = 3;
    *x = p;
}
int main() {
    str* y;
    do_something(&y);
    printf("%d", y->y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the program below. Your program needs some correction.

```
struct ceva
{
    int y;
};

typedef struct ceva str;

ceva* do_something()
{
    str *p = (str *)malloc (sizeof (str));
    p->y = 3;
    return p;
}

int main(void)
{
    str *y = (str *)malloc (sizeof (str));;
    y->y = 2;
    y = do_something ();
    printf ("%d", y->y);
}
```

Comment: The answer is more valuable if it contains comments about changes (what did you change and why)